# Headroom of cathodyne phase inverter (in vacuum tube amplifier)

Tags: amplifier, gain, vacuum-tube

I know that gain of cathodyne is almost 1, so if it's going to produce 12V peak output, it has to take 12V peak input.
 However, if the bias is set to something like (-)1-1.5V, then peak voltage of input signal has to be smaller than 1.5V is we want to avoid distorition, right?
That's how I imagined this situation until I found this somewhere:

> Of course, as with a cathode follower, a bias of -2V does not mean that the stage will overdrive if we input more than 2Vpk, the stage has roughly unity-gain remember!

Okay, so there is some magic happening in the background, maybe it has something to do with cathode resistor drop?
I couldn't find anything else on the internet that would help me understand what's happening here.
Could somebody explain this behavior of cathodyne circuit, and show a way to calculate actual peak voltage of input signal before overdrive happens, or provide links to articles where this is explained?

EDIT:
-1.5V grid voltage refers to cathode voltage, I'm totally aware that actual grid to ground voltage is positive.
Let's say we need 12V peak signal for power stage. That means output voltage of cathodyne will vary from Vq-12 to Vq+12 (Vq is quiescent voltage).
Let's assume cathode is at 100V in relation to groud. Grid is therefore biased to 98.5V.
If gain is 0.98(let's assume it's 1), then input must also have amplitude of 24V if we want output to have amplitude of 24V.
Actual voltage at grid at time t is Vbias + Vsignal(t).
Minimum Vsignal(t) is -12V, and maximum is +12V, since gain is 1, and we need 24V amplitude in next stage.
So minimum grid voltage is Vbias + min(Vsignal(t))= Vbias - 12V = 86.5, and maximum grid voltage is Vbias + max(Vsignal(t))=Vbias + 12V = 110.5.
Therefore maximum grid voltage is above cathode voltage, so grid to cathode voltage is positive, and saturation occurs.

Of course, since I know this is not what actually happens, there must be a mistake somewhere. Why doesn't grid voltage actually exceed cathode voltage, when peak of signal voltage is greater than difference between grid and cathode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *maybe it has something to do with cathode resistor drop?*

It **totally** has something to do with the cathode resistor drop. The bias setting of -1 volt to -1.5 volt refers to the voltage between grid and cathode and not from grid to 0 volts. A cathodyne has a cathode resistor and, if the anode quiescent current is 1 mA then that cathode resistor also takes that current and raises the cathode to a much higher quiescent voltage (say 40 volts using a 40 kohm cathode resistor). This will mean that the actual bias point for the grid is  38.5 volts to 39 volts and now, with a 24 volt p-p signal on top there is no problem.

> *if the bias is set to something like (-)1-1.5V, then peak voltage of
>   input signal has to be smaller than 1.5V is we want to avoid
>   distorition, right?*

No, you are not accounting for the fact that the cathode voltage, under quiescent conditions might be 30 to 50 volts above 0 volts and this is due to anode current and the presence of the cathode resistor.

### Simulation showing ECC82 waveforms

[image]

- Cathode quiescent voltage = 50 volts
- Anode quiescent voltage = 120 volts
- Grid self-biased (like the more recent JFET type bias)

48 volt p-p input signal: -

[image]

Grid voltage stays below cathode voltage always.

72 volts p-p input signal: -

[image]

Now we see a difference - the ECC82 enters saturation and the grid voltage rises 0.6 volts above the cathode. Anode bottom peak is showing signs of heavy saturation.

Comment: Maybe grid, not gate?

Comment: @Marla yes, you are right.... fixing......

Comment: I know that -1.5V refers to voltage between grid and cathode, this is not what I meant. I'm sorry if question was not clear, I'm not a native speaker. Could you please take a look at my edit?

Comment: OK - you have to choose a tube/valve with the appropriate characteristic and load-line so that saturation is avoided. If saturation is entered a little bit then sure, the grid voltage will go positive with respect to the cathode.

Comment: Yeah, now I understand, because of large cathode resistor, when grid voltage increases, cathode voltage also increases, so actual variation in voltage difference between grid and cathode is much smaller than variation in grid voltage. Btw, what software did you use for this simulation?

Comment: @JK it's called micro-cap 12 and is now fully free sine they decided to stop trading last year. I've used it since 2005 and it's awesome and comes with all models and libraries that used to be shipped with it when it cost circa $4k.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry for being a bit off-topic, I downloaded the software, it's really nice. Do you know how to implement transformer for push-pull stage in micro-cap? The problem is that it needs to have 40% screen taps for ultralinear configuration, like Hammond 1650HA for example.

Comment: Use several inductors and interconnect them as appropriate for the various taps then, link all the inductors together using a component called "k" (under passive components). Enter all the inductor names like "L1 L2 L3 L4 etc.." and enter a coupling factor called k. Turns ratio is defined as square root of inductance ratios hence 1 uH and 100 uH have a 1:10 ratio. K values smaller than 1 result in leakage inductance. For something like a Hammond 1650, I believe the k value would be close to 99% (k = 0.99) to avoid excessive leakage. Good luck.

Comment: @Andyaka I used micro-cap to simulate my amp project, and everything is just fine, except the power stage. It's a push-pull power stage with 2 EL34s. The problem is that power dissipation on EL34 anodes is going up to 200W, which is insane. I did exactly as you said, and to eliminate the possibility that it's just my bad design I copied power stage from valvewizard.co.uk, and it's still reaching insane power. You said you have experience with micro-cap and I guess with valve amps too, so if you have some old design of push-pull power stage, could you please share the circuit files?

Comment: @JK Raise a new question and show the circuit that is giving you problems. If you have already done this please send a link so I can take a look. I've never designed a push pull stage using valves BTW.